# Design a FA to accept L, where L = Strings in which ‘a’ always appears tripled

Tags: finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa

Design a FA to accept L, where L = {Strings in which ‘a’ always appears tripled} over the input set Σ = {a, b}.

This is my solution (A is start state):

[image: DFA]

From what I understand the question doesn't say it should always contain "a",
it should also accept strings like {b,bb,bbb}. Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks correct to me, assuming [A] is marked as a start state. However, it does reject strings like `"aaaa"` which could be valid depending on the interpretation of the question. In this example, `"a"` is quadrupled, but you could interpret that as two overlapping triples. I think your interpretation is more reasonable, but you might want to get clarification to resolve the ambiguity. Same for `"bababa"`, in which a "triple" of `"a"`s appear, but they're not adjacent. Again, probably not the intent, but good to clarify that.

Comment: A couple of links that might be relevant on a quick search: [1](http://courses.washington.edu/css448/zander/Notes/reg343ans.txt) and [2](https://www.slideshare.net/hadiha12/automata-theory-76299839)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution appears right to me! It really depends on the interpretation of the question. I also interpreted that `a`'s could also be separated, as long as they were always tripled.

> abbabbbab should be accepted as `a`'s are tripled always, come in threes.

You should make sure of that! I also did this FA in the case above, but my generic understanding of the question would be your interpretation which looks fine!

[image: FA automata tripled a's]